# Is there any general purpose breadcrumbs management library/code in .net?

Tags: .net, breadcrumbs, sitemappath

I want to make a msdn style breadcrumbs navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - look at the [SiteMapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.aspx) and the other menu/site navigation controls in Visual Studio toolbox.

Comment: I know that but it is too trivial!

Comment: Actually there is quite a lot of configuration available to you using the controls in combination. If they are still too trivial, write your own.

Comment: If all you want is MSDN style breadcrumbs, the SiteMapPath et. al. should be more than enough.